# Latest firefox package for Solaris 10

Tags: firefox, solaris

How to download latest Firefox (49.0) package for Solaris 10.
Please share the build procedure to create Firefox package for Solaris 10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find [this page](https://unixpackages.com/packages/mozilla)
Latest version now for Solaris: `Firefox-52.0.2esr`

With a notice:

> ---
>
> X multithread is re-enabled on Solaris 10.
> If you have drag & drop X hang issue, update your Xserver or stay with 45.x.
> If you are on Sun Ray, stay with 45.x.
>
> Solved the exit crash issue.
>
> Fontconfig 2.8.0 or above is required for version > 45.0.
> A library of fontconfig 2.8.0 is included in Firefox/Thunderbird
> for Solaris 10 contrib build.
> For OpenSolaris, you need to install Fontconfig 2.8.0 by yourself.

**[Updated]**

You can check this [link](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0.2esr/contrib/solaris_pkgadd/)

Comment: Thanks for your update, but we required Solaris package latest Firefox version 48.0

Comment: Where i can find package for solaris in this link "https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0b9/"

Comment: @user4319657 I think, lastest version for Solaris: 45

Answer (score 0):

Oracle shared a [link](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.2.0esr/contrib/) which provided Solaris package only for Firefox 45.2.0esr.
But Firefox 45.2.0 have multiple vulnerabilities. Need latest Firefox 48.0 or 49.0 package for Solaris.

Comment: Oracle only provides [the ESR releases of Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/), which get the security fixes without all the new feature churn of the rapid releases, and the [current ESR series is 45.x](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Firefox that I have found and that works fine on Solaris 10 on Sparc is 52.0.2 ESR.

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.0.2esr/contrib/

Extract it and run it with `./firefox`